# Nested Custom object in flutter not working

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add a document to my firestore with object AnswerModel where it is giving me error `Invalid argument: Instance of 'UserContact'`.

Here is the logic Used to creat the document but exception is triggered here which is shared above.

```
static Future<bool> saveAnswer({required AnswerModel answerModel}) async {
    bool isAnswerCreated = false;
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('answers')
        .add(answerModel.toMap())
        .then((value) {
      isAnswerCreated = true;
    }).catchError((error) {
      Logger().e('$className::createAnswerModel::error: $error');
      isAnswerCreated = false;
    });
    return isAnswerCreated;
  }
```

For AnswerModel class, It has a list of UserContact which is defined below.

```
class AnswerModel {
  String? id;
  bool? forUserContact;
  List<UserContact>? userContactOptions;


  AnswerModel({
    this.id,
    this.forUserContact = false,
    required this.userContactOptions,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        'forUserContact': forUserContact,
        'userContactOptions': userContactOptions,
        //'icon': ,
      };

  AnswerModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    userContactOptions = json['userContactOptions'] == null
        ? null
        : json['userContactOptions'].cast<UserContact>();
    forUserContact = json['forUserContact'] ?? false;
  }

  factory AnswerModel.fromFirestore(
    DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot,
    SnapshotOptions? options,
  ) {
    final data = snapshot.data();

    return AnswerModel(
      id: data?['id'],
      userContactOptions: data?['userContactOptions'] == null
          ? null
          : data?['userContactOptions'].cast<UserContact>(),
      forUserContact: data?['forUserContact'],
    );
  }
}
```

For UserContact, Below is the model which is used to created recoed.

```
class UserContact {
  String displayName;
  String phoneNo;
  int id;

  UserContact({
    required this.displayName,
    required this.phoneNo,
    required this.id,
  });

  factory UserContact.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return UserContact(
      displayName: json['displayName'] as String,
      phoneNo: json['phoneNo'] as String,
      id: json['id'],
    );
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        'displayName': displayName,
        'phoneNo': phoneNo,
        'id': id,
        //'icon': ,
      };

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'displayName': displayName,
      'phoneNo': phoneNo,
      'id': id,
    };
  }

  @override
  String toString() =>
      'UserContact(displayName: $displayName, phoneNo: $phoneNo, id: $id)';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In toMap() of AnswerModel, try:

```
...
'userContactOptions': [
      ...(userContactOptions ?? []).map((e) => e.toMap()).toList()
    ],
...
```